# How to achieve automatic sign in included in Android app, after installing it?

Tags: android, google-signin

I've installed Google Keep, a to-do Android app made by Google and I've noticed that after opening for the first time, I was already signed in with my phone's account.
How are they achieving this? I'm trying to do the same in another app I'm working on.

Comment: I didn't even thought that is possible to achieve what Google Keep did.
I'm trying to make sure that a trial app is not installed again when the trial ends (resetting the trial basically).
I've tried getting user's phone account, IMEI, or phone number. None is reliable unfortunately.
Logging in the user at once with app install would allow me to achieve that.

Comment: Use SharedPreference to store the user's status whether he is logged in or out. Also save user's id (generated by your backend) or email to get his information if he is logged-in else show the login page.

Comment: @beginner, the user is signed in without him know.

Comment: See if [cross-platform_single_sign_on](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#cross-platform_single_sign_on) helps you...

Comment: @Lal it means that I gave authorization to Google Keep, let's say, on web.
Therefore it automatically signs me in. However, I don't know how is the Android app detecting if I gave it authorization on web. It must first get my account. How is it doing this...?